# Windows 8.1 RDP -shadow session

Tags: rdp, remote-desktop-services, windows-8.1

Is it possible to establish RDP shadow session in Win 8.1 Pro VM on Win 8.1 Pro Host?

I can RDP into the VM  from an external client (credentials saved):

```
 mstsc.exe /v:68.560.92.1
```

In the VM I get the session Id using `query session`  yielding rdp-tcp#20

Then on another external client I do

```
 mstsc.exe /v:68.560.92.1 /shadow:rdp-tcp#20      Result: "This computer name is invalid"
 mstsc.exe /v:68.560.92.1 /shadow:20              Result: "This computer name is invalid"
 mstsc.exe /v:68.560.92.1                         Result: Success, but kicks off other client
```

Some things I've done:

1. disabled entire firewall  on VM (for testing)
2. Set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/TerminalServer/AllowRemoteRDC  to 1
3. Enabled File and Printer sharing on VM

Is this specifically not available without Win Server or full VDI deployment?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Even if you found a "hack" solution that allowed for it, that would be violating Microsoft's EULA. What you are trying to do (shadow an RDP session) is **only possible on a server OS** and this is very much by design. Sorry.